# how to hide the ugly aws s3 url - RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, rails-activestorage

My RoR app is on Heroku and active storage is configured correctly. However, when I'm in the app and fetch the uploaded document, the url is something like `https://cremers.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cx9xy0pmbieagvuw8a0vzcnfhvcc?response-content-disposition=inline%3B filename%3D"Digeste_9.1.pdf"%3B....`

How to change this to a "normal" url, like https://www.cremers.fr/documents/digest_9.1.pdf ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a route/controller to act as a sort of proxy. I've done exactly this, below is roughly the code I used, edited for your specifics.

I did not test this with your settings, obviously, and I wasn't using ActiveStorage in my case, so you might need/want to adjust, but this should get you started:

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/documents/:filename.:format.:compression', to: 'documents#show'
end
```

```
# app/controllers/documents_controller.rb

require 'open-uri'

class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    bucket_name = 'cremers'
    aws_region = 'eu-west-1'
    filename = params[:filename]
    s3_url = "https://s3-#{aws_region}.amazonaws.com/#{bucket_name}/#{filename}"
    data = open(s3_url)
    send_data data.read, type: data.content_type
  end
end
```